# Est-ce qu'il existe des adjectifs périodiques après « millénal » ?

Tags: adjectifs, nombres, indications-de-temps

On peut probablement utiliser les préfixes *bi-*, *tri-*, etc, mais est-ce qu'il y a quelque chose après *millénal*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Millénal* est inconnu dans *CNRTL*.

En revanche on utilise *centennale*

> Une crue *centennale* arrive approximativement une fois tous les cent ans.

Il semblerait qu'il n'y ait pas d'événement 'millénal' constaté par un seul homme !

Peut-être que le néologisme arrivera bientôt, mais l'usage est de dire :

> C'est un phénomène qui arrive tous les *X* ans.

.. et là on peut remplacer *X* par dix-mille, cent-mille, million, . . .

Answer (score 4):

Comme le montre le [ngram ci-dessous](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mill%C3%A9nal%2Cmill%C3%A9nale&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmill%C3%A9nale%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

le mot *millénal* /*millénale*, a fait son apparition en 1948. Cette année là il y a eu de [grandes crues](http://www.irma-grenoble.com/05documentation/04dossiers_articles.php?id_DTart=75&id_DT=8&PHPSESSID=14d97edbc7e158e72bed86a4f9192475) dans l'est de la France.

Présent dans le [wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mill%C3%A9nal) et dans [wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crue_centennale#Crue_mill.C3.A9nale) il ne se trouve pas encore dans tous les dictionnaires mais il est très couramment employé dans des publications techniques ou scientifiques traitant d'hydrologie, pour parler du débit d'un cours d'eau ou de types de crues.

Bien que le ngram ne relève aucune occurrence du mot au masculin dans des livres, on en trouve sur internet :

> [En général, on se base sur le débit qui est dépassé en moyenne tous les cent ans, appelé débit  centennal, ou tous les mille ans, débit millénal, pour fixer le dimensionnement des ouvrages](http://mpt2013.fr/simulation-de-pluies-extremes-dans-les-cevennes/).

Mais il est bien sûr plus fréquent au féminin :

- > [On parle de crues annuelles, décennales, centennales, millénales](http://www.senat.fr/rap/r01-034-1/r01-034-113.html).
- > [Caler les ouvrages non résistants plus haut pour éviter le contournement des ouvrages résistants et assurer une protection élevée (millénale) au droit des secteurs urbanisés](http://www.symadrem.fr/le-plan-rhone/etudes-du-plan-rhone/326-etude-de-calage-precis-entre-beaucaire-et-arles).
- > [Analyse des crues millénales simulées](https://extraflo.cemagref.fr/resultats/2-3-comparaison-des-methodes-de-predetermination-des-pluies-et-crues-extremes/hydrogrammes-de-crue-simulation-de-cotes-dans-une-retenue-version-aout-2013/preview_popup/file)
- > [un vent de période de retour 50 ans soufflant pendant une crue de projet (entre millénale et décamillénale en cas de menace pour la sécurité publique) sur une retenue qui se trouve donc à la cote des plus hautes eaux](http://www.set-revue.fr/les-vagues-dans-les-retenues-d-altitudes-analyse-et-methodes-pour-la-prevention/texte)

Après avoir lu [ceci](https://www.druide.com/enquetes/adjectifs-de-p%C3%A9riodicit%C3%A9) :

> On trouve souvent la graphie millénal au lieu de millennal. Cette dernière nous semble toutefois préférable, car elle s'intègre à la série des adjectifs en -ennal.

J'ai lancé une recherche google sur millennal, je n'ai trouvé qu'une seule entrée pertinente. Donc restons sur millénal.

« Millénale » est un adjectif qui exprime une périodicité je ne sais pas ce que tu appelles « adjectifs périodiques » qu'on pourrait placer après ce mot. 
Le seul dérivé de millénal que je connaisse est décamillénal (qui a lieu environ tous les dix mille ans).

> [le débit décamillénal est estimé autour de 20m3/s.](http://www.eurolegales.com/Annonce/AvisAdministratif/Vosges/LA-BRESSE/L-Est-Republicain/Avis-d-appel-public-a-la-concurrence-TQMB.html)

Je n'ai jamais rencontré ni bimillénal ni trimillénal, pas plus que bicentennal ou tricentennal d'ailleurs (ce qui ne veut pas dire que ça n'a jamais été employé).